# ExtUtils::MakeMaker doesn't generate make target to install dependencies for development

Tags: perl, makemaker

I'm building a Perl module.  Makefile.PL has

```
WriteMakefile(
    PREREQ_PM         => {
      'DBI' => '>= 1.641, < 2',
      # etc, ...
    },
    TEST_REQUIRES => {
      'Test::More' => 0,
    },
    # more stuff ...
);
```

Recently, my ~/perl5 tree got corrupted (PERL5LIB=~/perl5) so I decided to rebuild it, so I blew it away. Doesn't WriteMakefile() generate some make target that will do this for me with all the modules/packages in PREREQ_PM and TEST_REQUIRES. Instead, it just prints warnings:

```
Warning: prerequisite DBI >= 1.641, < 2 not found.
```

So I have to start re-installing all these by hand in order to run tests.  For my small project, this isn't such a problem, but what if the project had many dependencies?  Isn't there a way to automate this?

Comment: The `cpan` utility automates it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Makefile` target that will do what you want, but the `cpan` tool will use the information in the `META` file created by `Makefile.PL` to fetch and install dependencies.

If you to use `cpan` offline, consider cloning CPAN using [CPAN::Mini](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN::Mini).